# Can one image be used for training cnn

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

Is it possible to train neural network with only one image data so it can recognize this only one image?

For example i want to develop a facial recognition software using cnn where their will be limited number of face it has to recognize. Can i only use those face data to train cnn?

Comment: yes you can do it. but what is the purpose of it?

Comment: yes, it's called one shot learning.